How can overrides package to babel-traverse on react vite ts project
I was getting some errors in my React application due to the "aes-everywhere" package, and to fix these errors, I "overrided" some packages and fixed many errors, but I could not fix the life related to "babel-traverse". Can you help me how to override this package, thank you.
npm audit

Screenshot
package.json
{
  .
  .
  .
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "overrides": {
    "underscore.string": "3.3.6",
    "trim-newlines": "5.0.0",
    "minimatch": "5.1.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "json5": "2.2.3",
    "js-yaml": "4.1.0",
    "getobject": "1.1.1",
    "extend": "3.0.2",
    "grunt": "1.6.1",
    "braces": "3.0.3",
    "micromatch": "4.0.8",
    "babel-traverse": {
      .
      .
      .
    }
  },
}

I researched similar errors but could not find a concrete answer. Thank you in advance for your help.

I solved the problem by adding the relevant packages => "babel-core": "6.26.3", "babelify": "10.0.0" and result: found 0 vulnerabilities
